# UIVIew endEditing:YES doesnt hide the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextfield, first-responder

I have a UIVIew which is a subview and it contains several UITextFields. One of these textfields (which is for DATE) should not be editable using the keyboard, instead of this I use a PopOver with a Datepicker inside.

I run a method when the `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` is reached. This method calls the `resignFirstResponder` on the DateTextField.

Everything works fine if the DateTextField is the first field to edit, but when another textField is edited and of course shows the keyboard and then try to edit the DateField, the keyboard doesn't hide and everything goes normal but with the Keyboard doing anything.

I have tried to call the method `endEditing:YES` before the `resignFirstResponder` but it doesn't work. I have tried to run the `endEditing:YES` and `resignFirstResponder` on the `didEndEditing` text field method but theres no way to get that keyboard out.

here is my method:

```
- (void)showDatePopOver:(id)sender{ 
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)sender;
    [sender resignFirstResponder]; // hide keyboard

    /** POP OVER LINES**/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` delegate method instead of resigning first responder in `didBeginEditing`:

This will allow editing on ALL BUT the `dateTextField` text field:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return (![textField isEqual:dateTextField]);
}
```

You should specify that your view controller is a text view delegate as well like so (in the interface declaration [.h file]):

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I also had to change the event UIControlEventEditingDidBegin to the UIControlEventTouchDown

Comment: Cool, glad you got it fixed!  Happy coding.